# Update Google Play Service error

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, firebase-authentication

Having issues running my application which is working the Firebase authentication tool.

When I get to the 'Create an Account' stage of the process, I am met with and 'error', which is telling me to update my Google Play Services.

[image: Screen Shot of Error]

I have tried manually adding the Google Play Service through `project structure > dependencies`, but to no avail - The issue stays the same.

**Module:app Gradle File**

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.XXX.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Have checked other threads in Stack but none seem to solve the issue.  Any help on this would be much appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This notification is reporting that the version of the Google support library installed on the phone must be updated to support the app you are trying to run.  Normally this support library is automatically updated when new versions are release.

You need to download an update from the Google Play Store.  If you tap on the notification, it should open the Play Store app on Google Play services.  Then tap on Update.

Comment: This will not allow me do that using the emulator. Once I click on the message it simply disappears.

Comment: Update: I have added to your answer below. Thanks for your nod in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Once I had added the Google Play Services libraries using `file structure > dependencies`, all that was need here was to create a new AVD.  It seems that the Google Play Services will not register with AVDs that already exist.

I then had to update Google Play.  This was done by clicking the `...` at the bottom of the control panel, the navigating to the Google Play tab.  Then click update:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is a helpful pointer to the new (December 2017) [emulator capability to update Google Play services](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/12/quick-boot-top-features-in-android.html).

Answer (score 0):

try this, if the play service is not updated then it will redirect you to update it  :

```
public boolean checkPlayServices() {
    GoogleApiAvailability apiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
    int resultCode = apiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if (apiAvailability.isUserResolvableError(resultCode)) {
            apiAvailability.getErrorDialog(this, resultCode,9000).show();
        } else {
            Log.i("error", "This device is not supported.");
            finish();
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```